# CSS: Bootstrap drowpdown hides behind grid cell

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ag-grid

Hi Have a grid implemented third-party library `AG-Grid`. This grid has editable feature to edit rows.

And while editing I am rendering `Bootstrap dropdown` to update value of `Year` column as shown in below example:

[Editable Grid - Dropdown Issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/uUMqtMSetEU9DUSa86uF?p=preview)

When I click on the `dropdown` its `li` elements are not displaying properly as it is hidden behind the grid.

Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: overflow is set to hidden on multiple levels here. You’d have to remove that, and some height restrictions as well ... doubtful whether the rest will still work the same as before after that. I think you’d be way better off by not appending the dropdown into that place in the DOM in the first place, but outside of that whole structure - and then just absolutely position it to show up in the right position.

Comment: @CBroe: That overflow hidden thing is rendered by ag-grid. So I cannot change it.

Comment: Of course you _could_, styling can be overwritten ... But as I said, I doubt the rest would still work if you tried that.

Comment: @CBroe: Can you give me an example of overflow hidden ?

Comment: What? Example of/for what exactly? Again, I don’t think it makes sense that you start messing with the formatting of the component, that is likely going to break something somewhere.

Comment: Never mind. I fixed it by removing overflow hidden for the particular cell. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but for anyone else looking:

If you set the [isPopup()](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#popup) function on your cell editor to return true you shouldn't have to fight with the CSS of the component.  Allows the dropdown to render over the other cells without any CSS edits.

> If you want your editor to appear in a popup (such as a dropdown
>   list), then you can have it appear in a popup. The popup will appear
>   over the cell, however it will not change the contents of the cell.
>   Behind the popup the cell will remain intact until after editing is
>   finished which will result in the cell being refreshed.