# ag-Grid cell containing Bootstrap dropdown menu clips menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ag-grid

I have an ag-Grid set up to show data with a cell on the right that displays a context menu.  This context menu, triggered by a button, uses a Bootstrap  dropdown menu.  When clicked, the button correctly triggers the display of the menu, but the ag-Grid cell hides the dropdown.  I have attempted to force overflow: visible on the parent element as well as the grid cell itself without success.  I have even attempted to set a z-index on the parent element and still haven't been able to get it to work.  The only slight success I have had is by setting overflow:scroll.  I can then see the dropdown if I scroll the contents of the cell.  Not exactly user-friendly.  Anyone have a suggestion?
NOTE: I've already attempted this: [CSS: Bootstrap drowpdown hides behind grid cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075340/css-bootstrap-drowpdown-hides-behind-grid-cell)

Thanks for any suggestions you have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So simple way from the referenced post: [`isPopup`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#popup) function

```
isPopup:function(){
  return true;
}
```

> Update :  plnkr sample

[image]

Worked [plnkr sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/govT9f8WMqoqWYWQpuiV)

Comment: This does not seem to work for me.  I may be attempting to use this in the wrong place.  Could you provide an in-code example?

Comment: OK.  Much further now.  Thanks!  However, in order for the cell to drop down the menu with one click, I had to add the following to `afterGuiAttached`:
`this.dropdown.focus();
this.dropdown.click();`
When stepping through this with the debugger, the dropdown becomes visible until I step out of the code, where ag-grid somehow closes the dropdown.  Any ideas how I can stop the ag-grid code from closing the popup?

Comment: you can create own logic with `select` and `options` and you will be able to handle all of the needed things.

Comment: I gave that a consideration while working your solution into my project.  Unfortunately, the dropdown HTML I'm working with is prepared and delivered by an API and modifying that code is very intensive (I know...not the best original solution, but I'm working with code I inherited).  I'll keep testing this, but maybe, in the meantime, someone may have a way to keep the Bootstrap dropdown from disappearing after the click action.

Comment: `$('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').parent().removeClass('open');` OR `$('.dropdown.open').removeClass('open');`

Comment: GOT IT!!  The code you've listed here to toggle the class should be in the gridOptions.onCellEditingStarted event handler.  I use: `$(".ag-popup-editor .dropdown).toggleClass("open");` to make sure the popup displays.

Comment: will it work if height is fixed and rows are scrolled

Answer (score 25):

`isPopup` only works in editable cells.

To use a bootstrap dropdown in a non-editable cell in ag-grid-community version 19:

1. Apply `overflow: visible` to `.ag-cell`, or, better, to a `cellClass` you apply
   to the cell in the column definition, e.g. `.actions-button-cell`
2. Set z-indexes so that the focused row appears above unfocused rows.

The CSS:

```
.actions-button-cell { 
  overflow:visible; 
}

.ag-row {
    z-index: 0;
}

.ag-row.ag-row-focus {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

That allows the dropdown to flow outside the cell and row.

If you want to also have the dropdown flow outside the grid, you can add something like this:

```
.ag-root,
.ag-body-viewport,
.ag-body-viewport-wrapper {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

See [plnkr sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/TgVg6uQYap1XcqRv?p=preview)

Comment: Hey I tried this but my popup looks like this: https://imgur.com/1Iau3Og
Any suggestions on how I could clean that up?

Comment: @Batman I would try setting the z-index of the popup higher than the rest of the row, or specifically setting the cell where you're seeing the overlap to 0.

Comment: Thank you, this took forever for me to find!

For the record, I had to add .ag-root-wrapper, .ag-center-cols-clipper, .ag-center-cols-viewport, and .ag-paging-panel to the `overflow: visible !important` rule

Answer (score 3):

If your grid is small, and your drop down has "escaped the cell" with the above "popup = true" callback, you may find that the drop down is now clipped by the grid...

This related problem, can be addressed below.
@Yair Cohen put me onto investigating the scss change,
and found this:
[Ag-Grid SCSS CHANGE](http://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3079)

Ag-Grid introduced a scss change (V19 - V20) to .ag-root-wrapper hiding overflow. This can be overridden with:

```
.ag-root-wrapper { overflow: visible; }
```

Placed after the ag-grid scss import - your drop down will also not be clipped by the grid.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when the cell have the style overflow hidden.
Override that by adding `overflow:visible` property
In angular2 ag-grid you can add cell style to `oveflow:visible`

`cellStyle: { "overflow": 'visible' }`

Comment: I was using the JavaScript implementation and tried this with my project without success.  I’ll re-try your solution however and report back. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Tried this.  Unfortunately, even with `!important` in place (necessary since the `.bootdrop` class overrides the cellStyle), the cell height still blocks the content.

Answer (score 1):

I did it successfully after going through many options. I also had a bootstrap dropdown in one cell and the dropdown for the top rows was coming clipped (appearing under other rows).

Here is the trick to solve it:

1. Make z-index high for the row which is currently in focus. ag-grid applies `ag-row-focus` class to the row with which you are interacting. In your case, if you are clicking on button to open dropdown, that row gets focus. so just make its z-index high

   `.ag-row.ag-row-level-0.ag-row-position-absolute.ag-row-focus`
   `{z-index: 999;}`

and other rows, which have `ag-row-position-absolute`, make their z-index 0

```
.ag-row.ag-row-no-focus.ag-row-level-0.ag-row-position-absolute {
z-index: 0;
}
```

Sorry, laz guy. I try everything to solve by CSS first.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this is all I needed in Angular and ag-grid 23:

```js
  .ag-cell-value,
  .ag-cell {
    overflow: visible;
  }
```

Comment: So - not having detail I guessed: - added this as css to the scss for the component containing the grid. Did not work. Was this css needed in the custom control?

Comment: It needs to be global... You can use ng-deep or put it in the globals stylesheet

Comment: Thank you, but global will affect all usages (yes I can be context specific, but I will need many of these cluttering my global css) - and ng-deep is slated to be deprecated...

Comment: Though it's deprecated, Angular still recommends to use it until a solution is found. From Angular docs: "The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools."

Comment: Thank you again. I found this: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3079 Indicating a change in grid scss from v19 to v20. Placing this after the import of the grid scss to override this change did the trick: .ag-root-wrapper {
  overflow: visible;
}

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to modify the row height upon clicking the field (name: 'actions') by adding the onCellClicked event handler as such:

```
                   onCellClicked: function(params) {
                    if(params.column.colId == 'actions'){
                        var row = gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(params.rowIndex);
                        if(row.rowHeight != 200) {
                            row.setRowHeight(200);
                        } else {
                            gridOptions.api.resetRowHeights();
                        }
                        gridOptions.api.onRowHeightChanged();

                    }
                }
```

Hopefully a better solution can be presented to allow the dropdown to display over the grid in the future without having to expand the row.

Comment: I am currently struggling with the same problem. Did you find a better solution? Setting the row height is equally ugly than the scrolling solution! ;)

Comment: Thank you, @un.spike! But unfortunately I am already using the isPopup function. The problem is, that my scenario is a little bit more complicated. I have a text on the left side AND three dots (...) on the right side and only if you click on these three dots, I want a bootstrap drop down to appear - only below these three dots. So in fact, I have two controls in one column. A label and a bootstrap dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just a "cellRenderer" to implement a Dropdown in a cell of a ag-grid. It's not necessary a "cellEditor"

- 'component-name'.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-status-management',
  templateUrl: './project-status-management.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-status-management.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectStatusManagementComponent implements OnInit {

  // Template of the Grid
  @ViewChild('agGrid', { static: false }) agGrid: AgGridAngular;

  // Template to the Select (Dropdown)
  @ViewChild('templateCell', { static: true }) templateCell: TemplateRef<any>;

  columnDefs: any;
  frameworkComponents: any;
  gridContext: any;
  data: any[];

  // Values shown on Dropdown
  availableStatus: WorkflowStatus[] = [
    {
      workflowStatusId: 1,
      name: 'InDesign',
      description: 'In Design'
    },
    {
      workflowStatusId: 3,
      name: 'SourceReviewed',
      description: 'Source Reviewed'
    },
    {
      workflowStatusId: 5,
      name: 'Translated',
      description: 'Translated'
    },
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setUpGrid();

    // Set the context of the ag-grid
    this.gridContext = {
      availableStatus: this.availableStatus,
    };
  }


  setUpGrid() {
    // setup columns
    this.columnDefs = [
    {
        colId: 'projectStatus',
        headerName: 'Status',
        field: 'workflowStatus.workflowStatusId',
        cellRenderer: 'GridActionButtonCell',
        cellRendererParams: {
          ngTemplate: this.stringStatusCell
        },
        width: 170,
    }];

    this.frameworkComponents = {
      GridActionButtonCell: GridActionButtonComponent,
    };
  } 
}
```

- 'component-name'.html

```
<div>
   ...
  <ag-grid-angular #agGrid 
    [rowData]="data"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [context]="gridContext"      
    [suppressRowClickSelection]="true"
    ...
    [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents">
  </ag-grid-angular>
  ...
</div>


<ng-template #templateCell let-row let-context="params">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row" style="height: 100%;">
    <select [(ngModel)]="row.workflowStatus.workflowStatusId">
      <option *ngFor="let status of context.context.availableStatus" [ngValue]="status.workflowStatusId">{{status.description}}</option>
    </select> 
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Define a template '#templateCell' containing a  element.

Notes:
 1 - "let-row" => each rowData of the Grid (in this case would be this.data[i])
 2 - "let-context="params" => it's the context that we assigned to the Grid in order to pass it variables. In this case we set a variable in Context called "availableStatus":

```
 availableStatus: WorkflowStatus[] = [
    {
      workflowStatusId: 1,
      name: 'InDesign',
      description: 'In Design'
    },
    {
      workflowStatusId: 3,
      name: 'SourceReviewed',
      description: 'Source Reviewed'
    },
    {
      workflowStatusId: 5,
      name: 'Translated',
      description: 'Translated'
    },
  ];

 ngOnInit() {
    ....

    this.gridContext = {
      availableStatus: this.availableStatus,
    };
  }
```

Comment: This looks like it *almost* worked, but it's missing the code for GridActionButtonCell :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around, to show drop down (by triggering context menu on left click on any row)

I used 'cellClicked' event to call the function which displays a context menu

HTML file:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
  class="ag-theme-material fill-vertical"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)">
```

TS file:

```
// this.getContextMenuItems returns an array of items for drop down
this.gridOptions.getContextMenuItems = this.getContextMenuItems;
// on click on any drop down row, this can be accessed from context object in params
this.gridOptions.context = { parentComponent: this }

// this function returns the rows of the drop down
getContextMenuItems(params) {

    if (!params.value) {
      return []
    } else if( prams.value) {
      return [
    {
      name: params.value.masterdesignname,
      action: () => { params.context.parentComponent.goToDetailPage(params.value.masterdesignid)   }
    }
  ]
    } else {
      return [
        'copy',
        'export'
      ]
    }
  }


  // this function is called when a row in ag-grid if left clicked (by the cellClicked event)
  onCellClicked(params) {

      const { rowIndex, node, column, event, value } = params;

      const cell = params.api.rowRenderer.rowCompsByIndex[rowIndex].getRenderedCellForColumn(column);

      cell.beans.contextMenuFactory.showMenu(node, column, value, event);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following CSS to show the BS dropdown in the AG-Grid table.

```
.ag-row.ag-row-level-0.ag-row-position-absolute.ag-row-focus {z-index: 999;}
.ag-row.ag-row-level-0.ag-row-position-absolute .ag-cell-focus {overflow: visible;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using version `25.3.0` and I had to use the below CSS to get the bootstrap dropdown to display correctly.

```
.ag-row-focus {
    z-index: 999;
}

.ag-cell-value,
.ag-cell {
    overflow: visible;
}
```