# How to implement search in a cell editor implementing column of ag grid?

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using a Cell editor  in a column like below
columnDefs = [
      {
        field: 'name',
        width: 300,
        editable: true,
        cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
        cellEditorParams: {
          values: [
            'Bob',
            'Harry',
            'Sally',
}]
Here the cell editor has only 3 values.What if there are 100 values.Is it possible to implement  a search field in the dropdown.If so how?
Thanks.

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Comment: @hari krish - a simple search for similar questions on stackoverflow got me this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389069/ag-grid-cell-containing-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-clips-menu . To answer your question. Yes it is possible. To know how?? Show us some code!