# ag-Grid (angular) Floating Filter contains Bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, ag-grid

I have a Bootstrap dropDownMenu displayed in **CELL** and in **FLOATING FILTER** in ag agid table,

the broblème is when dropDonwMenu is triggered, the menu is hidden in cell, like in the picture.

[image]

I solved this broblème for the **CELL** by adding:

- suppressRowTransform: true for the gridOptions
- cellStyle: { overflow: 'visible' } for the columnDefs

Like indicated in this post [ag-Grid cell containing Bootstrap dropdown menu clips menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389069/ag-grid-cell-containing-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-clips-menu):

but, I can't solve this for the **Floating Filter,**

you can see the [sample in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vb72qy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fexample-render%2Fexample-render.component.less,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.less)

Thanks for any suggestions you have!

Answer (score 3):

You can [instruct](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/api#NgbDropdown) ng-bootstrap to append dropdown menus to the `body` element instead of the parent:

```html
<div class="btn-group" ngbDropdown container="body">
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3zdpu?file=src/app/example-render/example-render.component.html)